# What does the @ symbol mean next to a repository when doing 'yum list'

Tags: centos, yum, repository

What is the meaning of the @ symbol next to the name of the repository in this output:

> yum list | grep jdk
>
> jdk.x86_64                           2000:1.7.0_25-fcs        @puppmst-repo

This is running in CentOS 6.4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Man page for yum says this under List Options -
`name.arch [epoch:]version-release repo or @installed-from-repo`

So I would say you installed jdk.x86_64 from puppmst-repo

Answer (score 0):

It means that the particular package is either available on that repo or installed from that repo.

Answer (score 0):

The @ denotes a rpm which is installed.

e.g.

1) Query installed rpms with "rpm" command:

```
 [root@m440 ~]# rpm -qa |grep gzip
    gzip-1.9-9.el8.x86_64
```

2) Now compare to "yum list" output

```
[root@m440 ~]# yum list |grep gzip
gzip.x86_64                1.9-9.el8      @rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms           
nbdkit-plugin-gzip.x86_64  1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+   rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms
```

This shows @ for "gzip" which is installed,
missing-@ for another rpm which is not installed.